# Menu and a ContextMenu for a aChartengine chart

Tags: android, achartengine

Is it possible? have anyone been doing this before? I don't know where to start.

I mostly need the menu, not the context menu.

My "BudgetPieChart" class

```
public class ExpensesByCategoriesPieChart extends AbstractChart{

    private DataToArray dta;

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return MyApplication.getContext().getString(R.string.ExpensesByCategoriesPieChartName);
    }

    @Override
    public String getDesc() {
        return "The budget per project for this year (pie chart)";      
    }

    @Override
    public Intent execute(Context context) {

        dta = new DataToArray();
        String[] categories = dta.expenseByCategoriesToArray();
        double[] values = dta.expensesValuesByCategoriesToArray();      
        int[] colors = dta.getColorsArray(categories.length);

        DefaultRenderer renderer = buildCategoryRenderer(colors);
        renderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(true);
        renderer.setZoomEnabled(true);
        renderer.setChartTitleTextSize(20);
        return ChartFactory.getPieChartIntent(context, buildCategoryDataset("Wydatki kategoriami", categories, values), renderer, "Wydatki");
    }

    public CustomGraphicalView createView(
            CustomGraphicalView customGraphicalView) {
        // what do I do here?
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by setting a menu?

Comment: just want be able open menu with the menu button, on a chart activity

Comment: Sounds to me you need to implement a context menu http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5351631/context-menu-in-android  Is this what you need ?

Comment: do you know what the achart engine is?

Comment: Yes I used it in one of my projects a month ago

Comment: Then you know that I don;t create activity file for a chart. Its beeing generated

Comment: Yes I know. I used my custom XML with buttons, list etc and I drew the chart on a RelativeLayout because it actually uses the onDraw method to display it. And from that I used my own data to generate it. And I messed with the onDraw method to further customise the chart. I don't have any source code on my home computer though :(

Comment: that sounds like some serious makeover :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK so here it is. In my case CustomGraphicalView extends org.achartengine.GraphicalView but you can extend whatever class you need.

```
 private CustomGraphicalView mGraphicalView = new BudgetPieChart().createView(this); // you edit the createView() with your input data for the graph
 private RelativeLayout chart_layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.chart_layout);
 android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams param = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width, height);   
 chart_layout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
 chart_layout.addView(mGraphicalView, param);
```

---

```
 public CustomGraphicalView createView(Context context) {
    double[] values = new double[] { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100 }; //your desired values
    int[] colors = new int[] { // Color.BLUE, Color.GREEN, Color.MAGENTA, Color.YELLOW, Color.CYAN (your desired colors)
    Color.parseColor("#ff3399ff"), Color.parseColor("#ff0066cc"), Color.parseColor("#ff613592"), Color.parseColor("#ff7d3493"), Color.parseColor("#ffe81f53"), Color.parseColor("#ffeb5531"), Color.parseColor("#fff6bb2d"), Color.parseColor("#fff39f2f"), Color.parseColor("#ffe0d347"), Color.parseColor("#ff78c200") };
    // remember to have enough colors to match the number of elements from the data array for each pie slice
    DefaultRenderer renderer = buildCategoryRenderer(colors);
    renderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(false);
    renderer.setZoomEnabled(false);
    renderer.setChartTitleTextSize(20);
    renderer.setAntialiasing(true);
    renderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(false);
    renderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    renderer.setPanEnabled(false);
    renderer.setShowLabels(false);
    renderer.setShowLegend(false);

    return CustomChartFactory.getPieChartView(context, buildCategoryDataset("Project budget", values), renderer);
}

@Override
public Intent execute(Context arg0) {
    // NOT USED
    return null;
}
```

---

```
public class CustomChartFactory {
/** The key for the chart data. */
public static final String CHART = "chart";

/** The key for the chart graphical activity title. */
public static final String TITLE = "title";

private CustomChartFactory() {
    // empty for now
}

/**
 * Creates a pie chart intent that can be used to start the graphical view activity.
 * 
 * @param context
 *            the context
 * @param dataset
 *            the category series dataset (cannot be null)
 * @param renderer
 *            the series renderer (cannot be null)
 * @return a pie chart view
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException
 *             if dataset is null or renderer is null or if the dataset number of items is different than the number of series renderers
 */
public static final CustomGraphicalView getPieChartView(Context context, CategorySeries dataset, DefaultRenderer renderer) {
    checkParameters(dataset, renderer);
    CustomPieChart chart = new CustomPieChart(dataset, renderer);
    return new CustomGraphicalView(context, chart);
}

/**
 * Checks the validity of the dataset and renderer parameters.
 * 
 * @param dataset
 *            the category series dataset (cannot be null)
 * @param renderer
 *            the series renderer (cannot be null)
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException
 *             if dataset is null or renderer is null or if the dataset number of items is different than the number of series renderers
 */
private static void checkParameters(CategorySeries dataset, DefaultRenderer renderer) {
    if (dataset == null || renderer == null || dataset.getItemCount() != renderer.getSeriesRendererCount()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Dataset and renderer should be not null and the dataset number of items should be equal to the number of series renderers");
    }
}
}
```

This should get you going further with your project :) Good luck!

---

```
public class CustomGraphicalView extends org.achartengine.GraphicalView {
/** The chart to be drawn. */
private final AbstractChart mChart;

/** The chart renderer. */
private DefaultRenderer mRenderer;

/** The view bounds. */
private final Rect mRect = new Rect();

/** The user interface thread handler. */
private final Handler mHandler;

/** The zoom buttons rectangle. */
private final RectF mZoomR = new RectF();

/** The zoom in icon. */
private Bitmap zoomInImage;

/** The zoom out icon. */
private Bitmap zoomOutImage;

/** The fit zoom icon. */
private Bitmap fitZoomImage;

/** The zoom area size. */
private final int zoomSize = 50;

/** The zoom buttons background color. */
private static final int ZOOM_BUTTONS_COLOR = Color.argb(175, 150, 150, 150);

/** The zoom in tool. */
private Zoom mZoomIn;

/** The zoom out tool. */
private Zoom mZoomOut;

/** The fit zoom tool. */
private FitZoom mFitZoom;

/** The paint to be used when drawing the chart. */
private final Paint mPaint = new Paint();

/** The touch handler. */
private ITouchHandler mTouchHandler;

/** The old x coordinate. */
private float oldX;

/** The old y coordinate. */
private float oldY;

public boolean isRotating;

private float mX1, mY1, pY1, pX1, mX2, mY2, py, px, lastAngle, angle_rotation, rotation;

/**
 * Creates a new graphical view.
 * 
 * @param context
 *            the context
 * @param chart
 *            the chart to be drawn
 */
public CustomGraphicalView(Context context, AbstractChart chart) {
    super(context, chart);
    setOnTouchListener(this);
    mChart = chart;
    mHandler = new Handler();
    if (mChart instanceof XYChart) {
        mRenderer = ((XYChart) mChart).getRenderer();
    } else {
        mRenderer = ((RoundChart) mChart).getRenderer();
    }
    if (mRenderer.isZoomButtonsVisible()) {
        zoomInImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(CustomGraphicalView.class.getResourceAsStream("image/zoom_in.png"));
        zoomOutImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(CustomGraphicalView.class.getResourceAsStream("image/zoom_out.png"));
        fitZoomImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(CustomGraphicalView.class.getResourceAsStream("image/zoom-1.png"));
    }

    if ((mRenderer instanceof XYMultipleSeriesRenderer) && (((XYMultipleSeriesRenderer) mRenderer).getMarginsColor() == XYMultipleSeriesRenderer.NO_COLOR)) {
        ((XYMultipleSeriesRenderer) mRenderer).setMarginsColor(mPaint.getColor());
    }
    if ((mRenderer.isZoomEnabled() && mRenderer.isZoomButtonsVisible()) || mRenderer.isExternalZoomEnabled()) {
        mZoomIn = new Zoom(mChart, true, mRenderer.getZoomRate());
        mZoomOut = new Zoom(mChart, false, mRenderer.getZoomRate());
        mFitZoom = new FitZoom(mChart);
    }
    int version = 7;
    try {
        version = Integer.valueOf(Build.VERSION.SDK);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // do nothing
    }
    if (version < 7) {
        mTouchHandler = new TouchHandlerOld(this, mChart);
    } else {
        mTouchHandler = new TouchHandler(this, mChart);
    }
}

/**
 * Returns the current series selection object.
 * 
 * @return the series selection
 */
@Override
public SeriesSelection getCurrentSeriesAndPoint() {
    return mChart.getSeriesAndPointForScreenCoordinate(new Point(oldX, oldY));
}

/**
 * Transforms the currently selected screen point to a real point.
 * 
 * @param scale
 *            the scale
 * @return the currently selected real point
 */
@Override
public double[] toRealPoint(int scale) {
    if (mChart instanceof XYChart) {
        XYChart chart = (XYChart) mChart;
        return chart.toRealPoint(oldX, oldY, scale);
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.save();
    canvas.getClipBounds(mRect);
    int top = mRect.top;
    int left = mRect.left;
    int width = mRect.width();
    int height = mRect.height();
    if (mRenderer.isInScroll()) {
        top = 0;
        left = 0;
        width = getMeasuredWidth();
        height = getMeasuredHeight();
    }
    mChart.draw(canvas, left, top, width, height, mPaint);
    if ((mRenderer != null) && mRenderer.isZoomEnabled() && mRenderer.isZoomButtonsVisible()) {
        mPaint.setColor(ZOOM_BUTTONS_COLOR);
        // zoomSize = Math.max(zoomSize, Math.min(width, height) / 7);
        mZoomR.set((left + width) - (zoomSize * 3), (top + height) - (zoomSize * 0.775f), left + width, top + height);
        canvas.drawRoundRect(mZoomR, zoomSize / 3, zoomSize / 3, mPaint);
        float buttonY = (top + height) - (zoomSize * 0.625f);
        canvas.drawBitmap(zoomInImage, (left + width) - (zoomSize * 2.75f), buttonY, null);
        canvas.drawBitmap(zoomOutImage, (left + width) - (zoomSize * 1.75f), buttonY, null);
        canvas.drawBitmap(fitZoomImage, (left + width) - (zoomSize * 0.75f), buttonY, null);
    }
    canvas.restore();
}

/**
 * Sets the zoom rate.
 * 
 * @param rate
 *            the zoom rate
 */
@Override
public void setZoomRate(float rate) {
    if ((mZoomIn != null) && (mZoomOut != null)) {
        mZoomIn.setZoomRate(rate);
        mZoomOut.setZoomRate(rate);
    }
}

/**
 * Do a chart zoom in.
 */
@Override
public void zoomIn() {
    if (mZoomIn != null) {
        mZoomIn.apply();
        repaint();
    }
}

/**
 * Do a chart zoom out.
 */
@Override
public void zoomOut() {
    if (mZoomOut != null) {
        mZoomOut.apply();
        repaint();
    }
}

/**
 * Do a chart zoom reset / fit zoom.
 */
@Override
public void zoomReset() {
    if (mFitZoom != null) {
        mFitZoom.apply();
        mZoomIn.notifyZoomResetListeners();
        repaint();
    }
}

/**
 * Adds a new zoom listener.
 * 
 * @param listener
 *            zoom listener
 */
@Override
public void addZoomListener(ZoomListener listener, boolean onButtons, boolean onPinch) {
    if (onButtons) {
        if (mZoomIn != null) {
            mZoomIn.addZoomListener(listener);
            mZoomOut.addZoomListener(listener);
        }
        if (onPinch) {
            mTouchHandler.addZoomListener(listener);
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Removes a zoom listener.
 * 
 * @param listener
 *            zoom listener
 */
@Override
public synchronized void removeZoomListener(ZoomListener listener) {
    if (mZoomIn != null) {
        mZoomIn.removeZoomListener(listener);
        mZoomOut.removeZoomListener(listener);
    }
    mTouchHandler.removeZoomListener(listener);
}

/**
 * Adds a new pan listener.
 * 
 * @param listener
 *            pan listener
 */
@Override
public void addPanListener(PanListener listener) {
    mTouchHandler.addPanListener(listener);
}

/**
 * Removes a pan listener.
 * 
 * @param listener
 *            pan listener
 */
@Override
public void removePanListener(PanListener listener) {
    mTouchHandler.removePanListener(listener);
}

@Override
protected RectF getZoomRectangle() {
    return mZoomR;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        // save the x and y so they can be used in the click and long press
        // listeners
        oldX = event.getX();
        oldY = event.getY();
    }
    if ((mRenderer != null) && (mRenderer.isPanEnabled() || mRenderer.isZoomEnabled())) {
        if (mTouchHandler.handleTouch(event)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}

/**
 * Schedule a view content repaint.
 */
@Override
public void repaint() {
    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            invalidate();
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Schedule a view content repaint, in the specified rectangle area.
 * 
 * @param left
 *            the left position of the area to be repainted
 * @param top
 *            the top position of the area to be repainted
 * @param right
 *            the right position of the area to be repainted
 * @param bottom
 *            the bottom position of the area to be repainted
 */
@Override
public void repaint(final int left, final int top, final int right, final int bottom) {
    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            invalidate(left, top, right, bottom);
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Saves the content of the graphical view to a bitmap.
 * 
 * @return the bitmap
 */
@Override
public Bitmap toBitmap() {
    setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
    if (!isDrawingCacheEnabled()) {
        setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    }
    if (mRenderer.isApplyBackgroundColor()) {
        setDrawingCacheBackgroundColor(mRenderer.getBackgroundColor());
    }
    setDrawingCacheQuality(View.DRAWING_CACHE_QUALITY_HIGH);
    return getDrawingCache(true);
}

}
```

---

```
public class CustomPieChart extends RoundChart {
public static int radius = 115;

float currentAngle;

/** Handles returning values when tapping on PieChart. */
private final PieMapper mPieMapper;

/**
 * Builds a new pie chart instance.
 * 
 * @param dataset
 *            the series dataset
 * @param renderer
 *            the series renderer
 */
public CustomPieChart(CategorySeries dataset, DefaultRenderer renderer) {
    super(dataset, renderer);
    mPieMapper = new PieMapper();
}

/**
 * The graphical representation of the pie chart.
 * 
 * @param canvas
 *            the canvas to paint to
 * @param x
 *            the top left x value of the view to draw to
 * @param y
 *            the top left y value of the view to draw to
 * @param width
 *            the width of the view to draw to
 * @param height
 *            the height of the view to draw to
 * @param paint
 *            the paint
 */
@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas, int x, int y, int width, int height, Paint paint) {
    // paint.setAntiAlias(mRenderer.isAntialiasing());
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
    paint.setTextSize(mRenderer.getLabelsTextSize());
    int legendSize = getLegendSize(mRenderer, height / 5, 0);
    int left = x;
    int top = y;
    int right = x + width;
    int sLength = mDataset.getItemCount();
    double total = 0;
    String[] titles = new String[sLength];
    for (int i = 0; i < sLength; i++) {
        total += mDataset.getValue(i);
        titles[i] = mDataset.getCategory(i);
    }
    if (mRenderer.isFitLegend()) {
        legendSize = drawLegend(canvas, mRenderer, titles, left, right, y, width, height, legendSize, paint, true);
    }
    int bottom = y + height - legendSize;
    drawBackground(mRenderer, canvas, x, y, width, height, paint, false, DefaultRenderer.NO_COLOR);

    currentAngle = 0;
    int mRadius = Math.min(Math.abs(right - left), Math.abs(bottom - top));

    // radius = (int) (mRadius * 0.35 * mRenderer.getScale());
    if (mCenterX == NO_VALUE) {
        mCenterX = (left + right) / 2;
    }
    if (mCenterY == NO_VALUE) {
        mCenterY = (bottom + top) / 2;
    }

    // Hook in clip detection after center has been calculated
    mPieMapper.setDimensions(mRadius, mCenterX, mCenterY);
    boolean loadPieCfg = !mPieMapper.areAllSegmentPresent(sLength);
    if (loadPieCfg) {
        mPieMapper.clearPieSegments();
    }

    // float shortRadius = radius * 0.9f;
    // float longRadius = radius * 1.1f;

    RectF oval = new RectF(mCenterX - radius, mCenterY - radius, mCenterX + radius, mCenterY + radius);
    // List<RectF> prevLabelsBounds = new ArrayList<RectF>();

    for (int i = 0; i < sLength; i++) {
        paint.setColor(mRenderer.getSeriesRendererAt(i).getColor());
        float value = (float) mDataset.getValue(i);
        float angle = (float) (value / total * 360);
        canvas.drawArc(oval, currentAngle, angle, true, paint);
        // drawLabel(canvas, mDataset.getCategory(i), mRenderer, prevLabelsBounds, mCenterX, mCenterY,
        // shortRadius, longRadius, currentAngle, angle, left, right, paint);

        // Save details for getSeries functionality
        if (loadPieCfg) {
            mPieMapper.addPieSegment(i, value, currentAngle, angle);
        }
        currentAngle += angle;
    }
    // prevLabelsBounds.clear();
    // drawLegend(canvas, mRenderer, titles, left, right, y, width, height, legendSize, paint, false);
    // drawTitle(canvas, x, y, width, paint);

}

public static int getRadius() {
    return radius;
}

@Override
public SeriesSelection getSeriesAndPointForScreenCoordinate(Point screenPoint) {
    return mPieMapper.getSeriesAndPointForScreenCoordinate(screenPoint);
}

}
```

Comment: I'll do this again, you deserved the pints :) I swear I'm gonna give you credits when I finish my app. Just let me have a smoke and finish my beer :P

Comment: bloody edit dissapeared again. Posted it as an answer. Gonna accept your answer anyway. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

To get a menu you need only 1 thing. You have to use GraphicalView on your own activity. In order to do that you'll need:

**Former BudgetPieChart class**

```
public class ExpByCatPieChartHelper extends AbstractChart{

    private DataToArray dta;

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return MyApplication.getContext().getString(R.string.ExpensesByCategoriesPieChartName);
    }

    @Override
    public String getDesc() {
        return "The budget per project for this year (pie chart)";      
    }


    public GraphicalView createView(Context context) {

            dta = new DataToArray();
            String[] categories = dta.expenseByCategoriesToArray();
            double[] values = dta.expensesValuesByCategoriesToArray();      
            int[] colors = dta.getColorsArray(categories.length);           

            DefaultRenderer renderer = buildCategoryRenderer(colors);           
            renderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(true);
            renderer.setZoomEnabled(true);
            renderer.setChartTitleTextSize(20);

            return ChartFactory.getPieChartView(context, buildCategoryDataset("Wydatki kategoriami", categories, values), renderer);
        }

    @Override
    public Intent execute(Context context) {
        return null;
    }


}
```

**Additional class with activity of your own:**

```
public class ExpByCatPieChart extends Activity{

    private IACharts pieChart = new ExpByCatPieChartHelper();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        GraphicalView mGraphicalView = new ExpByCatPieChartHelper().createView(this);
        setContentView(mGraphicalView);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.chart_settings_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
        switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.chart_settings:
            Intent i = new Intent(this, PieChartSettings.class);
            startActivityForResult(i, 0); 
            return true;
        case R.id.home:
            finish();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);
    }



}
```

And this is pretty much everything. You get a default achart view and seit it as a content of a new activity. Viola :)

Comment: Achartengine is a very useful library. I'm sure gonna use it more in the future :)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to create a context menu [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9775909/achartengine-graphicalview-onclicklistener-not-working). Once the renderer (`XYMultipleSeriesRenderer`) is `setClickEnabled(true);` you can use `onCreateContextMenuListener` in the usual way.