# AChartEngine can't receive clicks and touch events

Tags: contextmenu, onclicklistener, achartengine

I'm trying to register onClickListener and onCreateContextMenuListener on a GraphicalView object. However it seems that the listeners are not receiving the clicks and long clicks.

How can I create Context Menu on GraphicalView objects?

Answer (score 0):

[aChartEngine, GraphicalView OnClickListener not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9775909/achartengine-graphicalview-onclicklistener-not-working)

I found the answer here. You have to setCLickEnabled on the renderer.